# VBA how to Create Multi Select ListBoxes in qualifying cells

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, activex

I am trying to achieve code where multi-select ListBoxes are added if Column 4 or 5 are selected and Column 2 in the same row has the string "has options".

The Listboxes contain values from named ranges called "option1" and "option2". Current Selections are output to the respective cell in Column 4 or 5 separated by commas.

This is the code I have in "This Workbook" object. It needs to work on all sheets.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Target.Column = 4 And Target.OFFSET(0, -1).Value = "has options" Then
            CreateOpt1PopUp Target
        End If
            If Target.Column = 5 And Target.OFFSET(0, -2).Value = "has options" Then
                CreateOpt2PopUp Target
            End If
        Else
            DeleteAllOpt1PopUps Target
            DeleteAllOpt2PopUps Target
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the code I have in a Module. The criteria has evolved and therefore I have amended the code multiple times to the point where it no longer works.

```
Private opt1SelectCell As Range

Public Function Opt1Area(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Range
    Const OPT1_COL As Long = 4
    Dim lastOpt1Row As Long
    With ws
        lastOpt1Row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
        If lastOpt1Row = 0 Then
            Set Opt1Area = Nothing
        Else
            Set Opt1Area = .Cells(2, OPT1_COL).Resize(lastOpt1Row, 1)
        End If
    End With
End Function

Public Sub Opt1BoxClick()
    Dim opt1BoxName As String
    opt1BoxName = Application.Caller
    
    Dim opt1Box As ListBox
    Set opt1Box = ActiveSheet.ListBoxes(opt1BoxName)

    Dim opt1List As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To opt1Box.ListCount
        If opt1Box.Selected(i) Then
            opt1List = opt1List & opt1Box.List(i) & ","
        End If
    Next i
    If Len(opt1List) > 0 Then
        opt1List = Left$(opt1List, Len(opt1List) - 1)
    End If
    opt1SelectCell.Value = opt1List
End Sub

Public Function Opt1ListArea() As Range
    Set Opt1ListArea = ActiveSheet.Range("option1")
End Function

Public Sub DeleteAllOpt1PopUps(ByRef selectedCell As Range)
    Dim opt1Box As ListBox
    For Each opt1Box In selectedCell.Parent.ListBoxes
        opt1Box.Delete
    Next opt1Box
End Sub

Public Sub CreateOpt1PopUp(ByRef selectedCell As Range)
    Set opt1SelectCell = selectedCell
    
    Dim Opt1PopUpCell As Range
    Set Opt1PopUpCell = opt1SelectCell.OFFSET(1, 0)
    
    DeleteAllOpt1PopUps selectedCell

    '--- now create listbox
    Const OPT1_POPUP_WIDTH As Double = 75
    Const OPT1_POPUP_HEIGHT As Double = 110
    Const OPT1_OFFSET As Double = 5#
    Dim opt1Box As ListBox
    Set opt1Box = ActiveSheet.ListBoxes.Add(Opt1PopUpCell.Left + OPT1_OFFSET, _
                                              Opt1PopUpCell.Top + OPT1_OFFSET, _
                                              OPT1_POPUP_WIDTH, _
                                              OPT1_POPUP_HEIGHT)
    With opt1Box
        .ListFillRange = Opt1ListArea().Address(external:=True)
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .MultiSelect = xlSimple
        .Display3DShading = True
        .OnAction = "Module1.Opt1BoxClick"
    End With
    
    '--- is there an existing list of options selected?
    Dim selectedOptions1() As String
    selectedOptions1 = Split(opt1SelectCell.Value, ",")
    Dim opt1 As Variant
    For Each opt1 In selectedOptions1
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To opt1Box.ListCount
            If opt1Box.List(i) = opt1 Then
                opt1Box.Selected(i) = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next opt1
End Sub
```

This is an example of the excel data.
[image]

How can I make this work and even improve it?

Comment: `where it no longer works.` I have lot of questions for you :) **1.** What doesn't work? **2.** What are you expecting? **3.**  What is actually the result?  **4.** Any error message? **5.**  What is `Opt1ListArea()`?

Comment: It no longer displays a ListBox. I am getting a runtime 1004 error: application defined or object defined error on this line ```Set Opt1ListArea = ActiveSheet.Range("option1")``` This is supposed to refer to the named range "option1" to display in the Option1 ListBox. I am not sure why this is an error as it worked fine at one point. I think this code is quite messed up that one error fix just points to another error. I am not very good with VBA either and a lot of it is over my head!

Comment: `Set Opt1ListArea = ActiveSheet.Range("option1")` What is the scope of the named range? Seems like the sheet which is active is not the intended sheet.

Comment: The scope is workbook. Ah ok I have removed "ActiveSheet." and the ListBox is populating now. I think this was something I changed when trying to fix something else! However now I am getting the same error on this line ```If Target.Column = 5 And Target.OFFSET(0, -2).Value = "has options" Then``` if clicking anywhere in columns 1 to 3.

Comment: Yes that is because when you click on column 1, there cannot be an offset `-2` ;) So handle that `If Target.Column > 3 Then` and then inside that put the above code.

Comment: perfect that removes the errors, however the ListBox remains visible if clicking anywhere in the first 3 columns, rather than being deleted. If clicking in columns 4 and up it is deleted as intended.

Comment: I am no sure but In the `Else` part of `If Target.Column > 3 Then` should you not be deleting the listbox?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234897/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-aye-cee).